# Is there any way to get any event when we are trying to move my application to trash in MAC

Tags: macos

I want to run my own uninstallation script related to my Application, when i am trying to move it  to trash. I want to get event, to see if move to trash  is triggered so that i will run my uninstallation script before moving it to trash

Comment: Don't quite follow you here. If it's in the trash, it meant the app was not running atm and once it's in the trash, it's not executable due to the trash folder permission. You should let the script remove your app and the related file all at once.

Comment: You mean i should write this clean removal, out if my app. As once it is moved to trash, it won't execute any of my code

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: When we try to move an application that is running to trash, we get an popup telling that we can't move to trash as application running. I want to get that event which helps me to show my own custom pop up before moving to trash

Comment: If your app is not sandboxed and has a demon running, it could be possible.

Comment: Yes i have a daemon running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstaller for a cocoa application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377015/uninstaller-for-a-cocoa-application)

Comment: Try using the demon to monitor the main bundle's location to achieve the goal you want.